# Rust executing methods concurrently

Tags: rust

I'm trying to learn rust and have some issues when trying to work with streams of futures. I have the following code

```
// Stocks: Vec<Stock> || Stock is my struct that implements method get_stock_depth
    let futures = stocks.iter();
    let futures = futures.map(|x| x.get_stock_depth());
    let stream = stream::iter(futures);
    let stream = stream.buffer_unordered(10);

    let result = stream.collect().await;
```

Stocks vector contains over 800 objects and i figured I'd like to limit concurrent executions. When i'm running the following code i get the following error

> type inside `async` block must be known in this context cannot infer
> type for type parameter `C` declared on the associated function
> `collect`

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This almost certainly has nothing to do with `async` or futures. This is just the normal requirement for `collect` to provide a type. `collect()` can create a number of return types and doesn't know what you want. You probably want a Vec like:

```
let result: Vec<_> = stream.collect().await;
```

You don't typically need to tell `collect` what to fill the `Vec` with (it can usually figure that out), so you can use `_`, but you do need to tell it what collection type you want.

You might also write this as:

```
let result = stream.collect::<Vec<_>>().await;
```

Or if this is the last line of a function that returns `result`, you can use type inference on the return type by dropping the assignment and the semicolon:

```
stream.collect().await
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. It took me embarrassingly long and i still didn't manage to solve it myself. Your answer works perfectly. So as far as i understand collection type is necessary here, cause collect can return few collection types right? I thought i messed up somewhere and it should've been deduced by compiler.
Again: thank you :-)

Comment: This is a very common mistake because `collect()` is a little weird in this way. It's handy that it could return lots of things (a VecDeque, a HashSet, or even a HashMap if you set up the iter correctly). But most of the time you want a Vec, and it's a little inconvenient and surprising that you have to call that out explicitly.

Comment: Specifically, `collect` can turn any `Iterator` into any `FromIterator` whose item type matches. This is incredibly general; for instance it can collect an iterator of `Result<T, E>` into `Result<Collection<T>, E>`, returning `Err` iff any of the iterated items was `Err` (and analogously for `Option<T>` with `None`). This generality is why `collect` frequently needs to be annotated.